# Java:how much does a "long" number take in memory?

Tags: java

do these two numbers both take equally 8bytes(64bit) in the memory?
long a=25L
long b=3543451651313213232168498L

Comment: A long is always 8 bytes, not to be confused with a `Long` which takes 16-24 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the size is fixed as per [the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2-210):

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively [...].

Answer (score 2):

Size of long is predetermined, it wouldn't change as per the number stored.

Comment: This question came to my mind when i read in a book that 0x3af3_32bc takes up 4 bytes in memory. but if what you said is correct then it should take 8 bytes in memory.

Comment: @user2633136 `0x3af332bc` is not a `long`. It's an `int`.

Comment: Int is of size of 4 bytes

Comment: Go through this to understand different primitive types in Java and its details, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

A long takes 8 bytes, whether it contains a zero (all bits 0) or -1 (all bits 1).

Answer (score 0):

yes, primitives are of fixed size and doesn't depend upon value they contain!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it takes the same amount.

A long value (even `0L`) takes up 64 bit (or 8 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes both take 8 bytes. Ask yourself the question how you would differentiate between a 32 bit integer and a 'half full' 64 bit long.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both take equal space. In Java , primitives are allocated a constant space based on the type of primitive. Objects on the other hand, may take variable amount of space over time.